# Want to compare to values of each cell present in two different google spreadsheet via app script but get error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

i Want to compare to values of each cell present in two different google spreadsheet via app script and change the cell's background color to show that cell is updated but i am getting an 
"Cannot read property "0.0" from undefined. (line 16, file "Code")"
i have tried opensheetbyname nd get its ranges still not workring. Googled this error no solution found
Here's my code

```
function myFunction() {
      var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1-l21-
      2B7KZ5sBaRh9kmUFOyeDyP1Pnp1_IqhVlAJJR0");

      var lastRow = sheet1.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getLastRow();
      var lastCol = sheet1.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getLastColumn();
      var data = sheet1.getDataRange().getValues();

      var sheet2 = 
      SpreadsheetApp.openById("1YOQjiHZXg86XGmFZ0d5noOoLdowc_JFn3wGjICymi_o");

      var lastRow2 = sheet2.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getLastRow();
      var lastCol2 = sheet2.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getLastColumn();
      var data2 = sheet2.getDataRange().getValues();

      for(i = 0; i<=lastRow2; i++){
        for(j = 0; j<=lastCol2; j++){
         if(data[i][j] != data2[i][j]){
           sheet1.getActiveCell().setBackground("#FFFF00");
           }
          }
         }
        }
```

**Updated Code**

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1Ibyd4QbrAhLMSD_GjIQYEwGCYrbtNTbMKF7vRA-Rc9Q").getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  var lastRow = sheet1.getLastRow();
  var lastCol = sheet1.getLastColumn();
  var data = sheet1.getDataRange().getValues();

  var sheet2 = 
  SpreadsheetApp.openById("1YOQjiHZXg86XGmFZ0d5noOoLdowc_JFn3wGjICymi_o");

  var lastRow2 = sheet2.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getLastRow();
  var lastCol2 = sheet2.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getLastColumn();
  var data2 = sheet2.getDataRange().getValues();

  for(i = 3; i<lastRow2; i++){
    for(j = 1; j<lastCol2; j++){
     if(data[i][j] != data2[i][j]){
       sheet1.getRange(i + 1, j + 1).setBackground("#FFFF00");
       }
      }
     }
    }
```

Also i have set trigger on edit for this to work

[Actual Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIBh2.png)

[After Code Execution Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qATEg.png)

[Desired Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0cPy.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data` and `data2` are 2 dimensional array. On the other hand, in your case, `lastRow2` and `lastCol2` means the length of array of `data2`. By this, when `i` and `j` of the for loop reach to `lastRow2` and `lastCol2`, the error occurs. So how about this modification?

#### From :

```
for(i = 0; i<=lastRow2; i++){
  for(j = 0; j<=lastCol2; j++){
```

#### To :

```
for(i = 0; i < lastRow2; i++){
  for(j = 0; j < lastCol2; j++){
```

#### Note :

- In your case, `data` and `data2` have to be the same length of array. Please be careful for this.

If this modification didn't work, can you show us your sample sheet? I think that it will help to think of solution. If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

### Edit 1 :

There are 2 parts for modifying. In these modifications, `sheet1` supposes the original sheet. Please modify as follows. Please input sheet name of original sheet.

#### 1

From :

```
var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1-l21-2B7KZ5sBaRh9kmUFOyeDyP1Pnp1_IqhVlAJJR0");
```

To :

```
var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1-l21-2B7KZ5sBaRh9kmUFOyeDyP1Pnp1_IqhVlAJJR0").getSheetByName("### sheet name of original sheet ###");
```

#### 2

From :

```
sheet1.getActiveCell().setBackground("#FFFF00");
```

To :

```
sheet1.getRange(i + 1, j + 1).setBackground("#FFFF00");
```

### Edit 2 :

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1Ibyd4QbrAhLMSD_GjIQYEwGCYrbtNTbMKF7vRA-Rc9Q").getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var lastRow = sheet1.getLastRow();
  var lastCol = sheet1.getLastColumn();
  var data = sheet1.getDataRange().getDisplayValues(); // Modified
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1YOQjiHZXg86XGmFZ0d5noOoLdowc_JFn3wGjICymi_o");
  var lastRow2 = sheet2.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getLastRow();
  var lastCol2 = sheet2.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getLastColumn();
  var data2 = sheet2.getDataRange().getDisplayValues(); // Modified
  for(i = 3; i<lastRow2; i++){
    for(j = 1; j<lastCol2; j++){
      if(data[i][j] != data2[i][j]){
        sheet1.getRange(i + 1, j + 1).setBackground("#FFFF00");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry the sheet is confidential. Hence, i can not show you the sheet but one thing i would like to tell you about the sheet is it both sheets are a exact copy of each other like a backup sheet. The idea behind is, that i made a backup sheet to compare the old values with new values(if someone in our offices edits the sheet). So if any edits are made to a particular cell its color will change in original sheet to tell its updated.

Comment: Also i will set the trigger later on that after a week time the new updated sheet will be backed up replacing the old backup and all the colors changed will be restored so that the sheet updates can be shown again next week. This way i thought of highlighting any updates made to the sheet. Also later on i will aim to make an auto update column that will only show latest updates at one place like new feeds in the spreadsheet only

Comment: I tried your suggestion. And error is gone but only A1 cell turned yellow even if it was blank

Comment: @Ankit Aggarwal I'm sorry for the inconvenience. And thank you for your additional information. I can understand the error in your question was removed. But, unfortunately, I cannot understand about your next question. In order to understand your situation, can I ask you about it? In your script, what role do sheet1 and sheet2, respectively? ``but only A1 cell turned yellow even if it was blank`` I cannot understand this mean. Can you show us your sample sheets for testing? Of course, that is not the confidential one. It will help to think of the solution. I'm sorry for my poor English skill.

Comment: you don't need to say sorry dear thanks for helping . My sheets are normal like when you create a new blank spreadsheet and fill in some data then make exact copy of the spreadsheet and start comparing the values for any change. After applying your tip my code started to work but it is not changing the background color for different values. See "if" statement used in the end of the code. There is the command implemented to change the color if values are mismatch for the same cell in any of the sheet

Comment: @Ankit Aggarwal Which sheet do you want to change the background color when the user's sheet is edited? Do you want to change the background color of the copied sheet?

Comment: i want to change the color of original sheet. Copied sheet is just a backup to find out any cell whose value is changed.

Comment: @Ankit Aggarwal I updated my answer from your comments. Please confirm it.

Comment: i have uploaded the screenshot of what happened after execution of edited code. This is the sample sheet and performed the function on the exact copy of the sheet. Hope this helps debugging

Comment: Also i started i from 3 and j from 1 as i dont wanted to compare the values of first 2 rows. so upper rows are not affected or else they would have turned yellow too

Comment: @Ankit Aggarwal About this ``Also i started i from 3 and j from 1 as i dont wanted to compare the values of first 2 rows.``, can you tell me where I can see it at your script? I couldn't notice about it. For this, I'm really sorry for my poor English skill. And I cannot understand your current issue. So can you update your question to the current issue using the detail information?

Comment: Sorry to confuse you with incomplete resources. Now i have updated my Question With all necessary info please look forward to it. I want when a value of a cell is changed that cell should become yellow

Comment: @Ankit Aggarwal Thank you for the additional information. I saw the additional 2 images. I think that he image of "After Code Execution Sheet" is the current situation. Can you show us the sample image of expected result? From your question, I couldn't understand about the result you want. I'm sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: I have attached the desired result image please look at it. I hope now have all the keys to ignite up your coding engine to reach destination :)

Comment: @Ankit Aggarwal Thank you for your additional information. I updated my answer. Please confirm it.

Comment: oh gr8...its works thnx a lot buddy. Now please explain me the details why it was failing. Difference between getValues() and getDisplay Values. Documentation says one returns object one returns string. I want to know the back end working of object. What values it stores and why was i getting that result before. That will help me learning. Thank you again buddy

Comment: @Ankit Aggarwal Thank you for your response.